# RN Image resizemode="contain" chops off portion of an image

Tags: css, react-native, image

[Image](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image) tag is used in React Native 0.70 to display image with `resizeMode="contain"`. According to RN doc, in "contain" mode, the full image is shown with uniformly shrinking (aspect ratio is maintained) if the image is large than the display area. Here is the original image 1515 x 1391, 783kB:

[image: 1515x1391]

This is the image in "contain" resizemode after the same image filled up the whole screen (android):

[image: The image filled up the whole phone screen]

Here is the view code:

```
 return (
      <GestureHandlerRootView>
        <GestureDetector gesture={pinch}>
          <GestureDetector gesture={pan}>
            <Animated.View style={styles.container}>
                  <Animated.View style={[{width: width * images.length, height, flexDirection: "row"}, swipeStyle]}>
                      
                    {images.map((img_source, i) => {
                        //const isActive = useDerivedValue(() => {return index.value === i});
                        const pinchStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
                          return {
                            transform: [
                              { translateX: (-width / 2 + focalX.value - offsetX.value)},
                              { translateY: (-height / 2 + focalY.value)},
                              { scale: scale.value },
                              { translateX: (width / 2 - focalX.value + offsetX.value)},
                              { translateY: (height / 2 - focalY.value)},
                              
                            ]};
                        }, []); 
                        return (
                        <Animated.View key={i} style={[styles.picture, pinchStyle]}>
                            <View style={[styles.image]}>
                              <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} style={styles.button}>
                                <View style={styles.button}>
                                  <CachedImage //<<==same as Image
                                              source={{uri:img_source.path.split("?")[0]}} 
                                              sourceAlt={{uri:img_source.path}} 
                                              resizeMode={"contain"} //<<==resizeMode used
                                              style={[styles.image, {maxWidth:"100%"}]}
                                  />
                                </View>
                              </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                            </View>
                        </Animated.View>
                        );
                    })}
                    
                    </Animated.View>
                </Animated.View>
              </GestureDetector> 
            </GestureDetector> 
        </GestureHandlerRootView>  

style={[styles.image, {maxWidth:"100%", maxHeight:"100%"}]}
    image: {
      flex:1,
      width: undefined,
      height: undefined,
},
```

As it can be seen, the aspect ratio has been maintained but only part of the image was shown while the edge part of the image was chopped off. `resizeMode="center"` is the same. How to show full image with `Image` tag while maintaining the same aspect ratio? Most likely the original image size is larger than the size of phone screen.

Comment: This kind of codes are not enough to rectify , what is the issue. Can you provide some more?

Comment: The image displayed was chopped off and not in whole.

Comment: Are you sure the View that it's contained within isn't wider than the display area? In particular the `<Animated.View style={[{width: width * images.length ...` bit is jumping out at me as a potential place where the View is defined too wide, but without knowing the values I can't say for certain. In either case `resizeMode="contain"` might be working correctly, only the container its in is wider than the screen

Answer (score 1):

check for the parent view width , I believe that you have given parent view more width than the screen width and the image is occupying it fully i.e. '100%'.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue was in your styles when you add undefined it took full size of image and when you add maxWidth and maxHeight it was not taking that.

You need to remove **maxWidth** and **maxHeight** and replace you **width** from **undefined** to

```
Dimensions.get('screen').width
```

I think it resolves your issue.